# Django serializer inherit and extend fields

Tags: django

I have these 2 serializers:

```
class BasicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = ('lengthy', 'touple', 'of', \
              'fields', 'like', '10', 'of', 'them')

class AdvandedSerializer(BasicSerializer):
    additional_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_additional_field(self, obj):
        return('not important')
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = ('lengthy', 'touple', 'of', \
              'fields', 'like', '10', 'of', 'them', 'additional_field')
```

This is obviously rather ugly code. I would like to get and extend the `fields` touple from `super()`, however I have no idea how.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can do:

```
class BasicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = ('lengthy', 'touple', 'of', 'fields', 'like', '10', 'of', 'them')

class AdvandedSerializer(BasicSerializer):
    additional_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_additional_field(self, obj):
        return('not important')

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        fields = BasicSerializer.Meta.fields + ('additional_field',)
```

Comment: Hey, how do i have to handle the 'not important'-part to show the correct result of an subquery?

Comment: What if my `BaseSerializer` defines `exclude` rather than `fields`? Is there any solution to this? Or is my only choice to replace it with `fields` and manually add all fields there?

Comment: IMHO this should be added as an example in the [DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializer-inheritance)

Comment: This is perfect, but if yo do not want nested fields, go for @anjaneyulubatta505 answer.

Comment: @emanuelsanga what do you mean by "nested" fields?

Comment: Am seeing the answers are similar now... Have no clue what i meant then

Comment: Working more than 4 years with DRF and I didn't know about this :) Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

we can do like

```
class AdvandedSerializer(BasicSerializer):
    # ... some code

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = BasicSerializer.Meta.fields + ('additional_field',)
```

Comment: more clean if you do not want nested json fields

Comment: instead of this **fields = BasicSerializer.Meta.fields + ('e_uuid', 'f_uuid')**. List works for me instead of tuple **fields = EmployerProfileSerializer.Meta.fields + ['e_uuid', 'f_uuid']**